# Does a keras model affect the size of input data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I mean, if a convnet model is fed in `n` models, it will give out `n` outputs right?
However when I tried this with a bottleneck model (using VGG16 convnet to build on top of), the VGG16 convnet returned 16 less outputs than the number of inputs.

This is the console output:

> `import numpy as np`
>
> `train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy'))`
>   `train_data.shape`
>   (8384, 7, 7, 512)
>
> `validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy'))`
>   `validation_data.shape`
>   (3584, 7, 7, 512)

The script which generated this output can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/darthv115/19b463c5b283f196065d927ea488a9bf).

The stack trace for the above script.

> Using Theano backend.
>   Downloading data from https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
>   **Found 8400 images belonging to 120 classes**. Saving train features...
>   **Found 3600 images belonging to 120 classes**. Saving test features...
>   Training top layers...
>   Compiling bottleneck model...
>   Training bottleneck model...
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File"pretrained_network.py", line 87, in 
> >     train_top_model()
> >
> > File "pretrained_network.py", line 82, in train_top_model
> >     validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
> >
> > File "/home/ashish/ml-projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py",line 845, in fit initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
> >
> > File "/home/ashish/ml-projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> >     line 1405, in fit 
> >     batch_size=batch_size)
> >
> > File "/home/ashish/ml-projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> >     line 1307, in _standardize_user_data
> >         _check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
> >
> > File "/home/ashish/ml-projects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> >     line 229, in _check_array_lengths
> >         'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
> >
> > ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays.
> >     **Found 8384 input samples and 8400 target samples**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies e.g. here in your script:

```
bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
        generator, nb_train_samples // batch_size)
```

It should be changed to:

```
bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
        generator, (nb_train_samples // batch_size) + 1)
```

Without this a `generator` is not called enough number of times.

Comment: Thanks for going through the entire code and finding that silly bug!

Comment: After hours of struggling with `generators` in `keras` that was easy to find :)